# Dados do login ficam visiveis na consola do browser

Tags: php

Faço o login desta forma:

```
<div class="container">

      <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="./index.php/valida">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Área Restrita</h2>
        <label for="inputnome" class="sr-only">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="inputnome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Senha</label>
        <input type="password" name="senha" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">Entrar</button>
      </form>
      <p class="text-center text-danger">
            <?php if(isset($_SESSION['loginErro'])){
                echo $_SESSION['loginErro'];
                unset($_SESSION['loginErro']);
            }?>
        </p>
        <p class="text-center text-success">
            <?php 
            if(isset($_SESSION['logindeslogado'])){
                echo $_SESSION['logindeslogado'];
                unset($_SESSION['logindeslogado']);
            }
            ?>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Faço a validação dos dados desta forma:

```
if((isset($_POST['nome'])) && (isset($_POST['senha']))){
        $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nome']); //Escapar de caracteres especiais, como aspas, prevenindo SQL injection
        $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);
        $senha = sha1($senha);

        //Buscar na tabela usuario o usuário que corresponde com os dados digitado no formulário
        $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome = '$usuario' && senha = '$senha' && situacoe_id = '1' LIMIT 1";
        $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
        $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);
if(isset($resultado)){
            $_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $resultado['id'];
            $_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
            $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] = $resultado['niveis_acesso_id'];
            $_SESSION['usuarioEmail'] = $resultado['email'];
            $_SESSION['usuarioSenha'] = $resultado['senha'];
if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "1"){
                header("Location: ./index.php/administrativo");
            }elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "2"){
                header("Location: ./index.php/colaborador");
            }elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "3"){
                header("Location: ./index.php/enfermagem");
            }else{
                header("Location: ./index.php/cliente");
            }
        //Não foi encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
        //redireciona o usuario para a página de login
        }else{  
            //Váriavel global recebendo a mensagem de erro
            $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha Inválido";
            header("Location: ./login");
        }}
    }else{
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha inválido";
        header("Location: ./login");
    }
```

O problema é que depois de fazer login, se consultar a consola do browser, tenho acesso ao utilizador e senha, como mostro na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O propósito do *Developer Tools* é registrar tudo que acontece com a página, *requests* e *posts* inclusive, então as informações que trafegaram estão lá, ele age como um *sniffer*, mas o objetivo não é revelar informações sensíveis.

Mas isso é temporário, na próxima requisição/navegação esses dados irão ser substituídos por outros quando a página recarregar, isso não acontece só no seu site, se abrir a ferramenta e logar em outro serviço, email, etc, vai ver que seu *request* inicial vai aparecer lá também, mas deixar aberto a ferramenta e deixar alguém ver, é como digitar a senha sem os "*" :)

Se estiver preocupado com isso, pode criptografar a senha antes de fazer o envio, e descriptografar do lado *server*.

Agora só uma observação, já que está falando em segurança, é realmente necessário salvar a senha do usuário na *Session* depois que já autenticou nessa linha de código?

`$_SESSION['usuarioSenha'] = $resultado['senha']`

Comment: sim, preciso de salvar a senha na Session porque se não salvar o login não é validado

Comment: é que não percebi por que precisa salvar a senha se já validou no banco que está correta e tem o "id" do usuário, mas é só uma observação